# How to update absolute expiration of existing cache items in MemoryCache.Default

Tags: .net, memorycache

I am using C# and .NET and I have a CacheItem stored in the MemoryCache.Default.

All I want is to update its absolute expiration without to reinserting it.

I want to just get the CacheItem and update its expiration.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it.

There is a 'Set' method in the MemoryCache object.

Thank you all.